# STEP 2016 Statistics Question

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification

Here is the question that I am attempting:

[image]

I have done all parts expect for the last one. The way I approached it was the following:

The probability that the card $C_i$ is in the $i$ th position is $\frac{1}{n}$. The probability that all of the other cards do not match their number is $\frac{n-2}{n-1}\times\frac{n-3}{n-2}\times \cdots=\frac{1}{n-1}$ giving the desired probability to be $\frac{1}{n(n-1)}$ which is false according to the markscheme. Can someone please explain to me why the approach I have used is wrong/ not applicable in this question?

Comment: What answer does the mark scheme give?

Comment: @A-levelStudent $\frac{1}{2 !}-\frac{1}{3 !}+\cdots+(-1)^{n-1} \frac{1}{(n-1) !}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let´s say that $n=4$ and we fix the first position. Then we are looking for the permutations $1XYZ$, where $X,Y,Z \in \{2,3,4\} \cap X\neq Y\neq Z$. Then you say that at the second position you do not put 2. That is a good idea, but it is not sufficient. At the third and fourth position there can be 2 cards in their position: $2134$. This case you would omit in your calculation.

So you have to use the [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of $n$ objects. At the end of this [paragraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement#Derivation_by_inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) it says that the number of permutation that leaves none of the $n$ objects fixed is

$$!n = n!- |S_1\cup\cdots\cup S_n|=n! \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$$
If you fix one object you must derange $(n-1)$ objects: $!(n-1) =(n-1)! \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$.

To obtain the probability you divide it by $(n-1)!$

Answer (score 0):

You've made two mistakes. One is to consider only one $i$. The other is to multiply the probabilities of dependent events.